# Is there a way to make a custom root node in a RABL feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I'm working on a RABL JSON feed and I'd like to make a custom root node where I can link to a particular object.

I have the object declared like so:

```
object @event
```

Here is the beginning of the output:

```
{
  - event: {
      id: 131,
```

I'd like to have it so that I can link to the particular object using the event_path(event) from where it says "- event". Is there a way to make a custom root node in RABL?

Answer (score 0):

I think this [post](http://engineering.gomiso.com/2011/06/27/building-a-platform-api-on-rails/) might have an answer to your question. Below code is taken from the blogpost.

```
# app/views/users/show.rabl
object @user

# Declare the properties to include
attributes :first_name, :last_name

# Alias 'age' to 'years_old'
attributes :age => :years_old

# Include a custom node with full_name for user
node :full_name do |user|
  [user.first_name, user.last_name].join(" ")
end

# Include a custom node related to if the user can drink
node :can_drink do |user|
  user.age >= 21
end
```